# Routing Test Fails with Matched Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes, omniauth

I have this line of code in my routes

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1 do
    match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sign_in#authenticate'
  end
end
```

And my test as

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Routing" do
  it "should route to sign_in#authenticate" do
    expect(post: 'api/v1/auth/:provider/callback').to route_to({ controller: 'api/v1/sign_in', action: 'authenticate',  format: 'json' })
  end

end
```

However, no matter what I do I keep getting the error

```
No route matches "/api/v1/auth/:provider/callback"
```

What am I missing here in order to make this test pass?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you're getting is because match defaults to a GET request, but you are testing a POST request in your spec. You should be able to fix the issue by changing the route to:

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sign_in#authenticate', via: :post
```

My personal preference is to use the post method instead of match, it just reads better to me:

```
post '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sign_in#authenticate'
```

Comment: Hmm.. it didn't work. It still returned that no route matches were found.